# jquery how do I combine data() objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two data objects stored on different nodes in the dom

ie

```
$('node1').data('id','1');
$('node2').data('id','1');
```

How do I combine these in order to attatch them to the **data** attribute in the ajax object

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/test.html',
  timeout: 3000,
  cache: false,
  data: // combined node1 and node2 here!,
  success: function(data){
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Here's how I'd do it:

```
data: {node1: $('node1').data('id'), node2: $('node2').data('id')},
```

...because jQuery will accept an object and generate the necessary URI-encoded representation for you (see the `data` parameter in [the `ajax` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

But you can also do it using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and string concatenation:

```
data: "node1=" + encodeURIComponent($('node1').data('id')) + "&" +
      "node2=" + encodeURIComponent($('node2').data('id')),
```

You can see why I prefer the first syntax. :-)

Either way, your script will see `node1` and `node2` parameters in the HTTP data (in your case, the query string, since your `ajax` call is using the default `GET` method).

If you wanted a single parameter with a combined value, just choose a separator (or don't use one) and combine the two values. Here's an example using an `_` for the separator:

```
data: {paramName: $('node1').data('id') + "_" + $('node2').data('id')},
// -or-
data: "paramName=" + encodeURIComponent(
                        $('node1').data('id') + "_" +
                        $('node2').data('id')
                     ),
```